# How to stop a PostgreSQL database with pg_ctl?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to stop the currently running database, because apparently EnterpriseDB on Mac OSX does not support Postgis. And the Postgis site tells me to use Postgres.app. But I cannot stop the currently running database with EnterpriseDB. I tried pg_ctl:

```
$ pg_ctl stop -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data
pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/postmaster.pid": Permission denied
$ sudo pg_ctl stop -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data
pg_ctl: cannot be run as root
$ cd /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami) .
$  pg_ctl stop -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data
pg_ctl: could not send stop signal (PID: 105): Operation not permitted
```

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: This post was about my issues installing EnterpriseDB and finally when i go it working: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262831/postgresql-not-in-path-after-installation I now realize it does not support Spacial

Comment: WHEN YOU USE postgresql on Mac OSX, USE Postgres.app: http://postgresapp.com. After installed, make sure you delete EnterpriseDB from your system and restart your computer and make sure Postgres.app is running. Then you can use the geospacial extension. I am pleading to you for your own mercy to use Postgres.app.

Answer (score 1):

I had to change owner of those files to user `postgres` and then shut it down via that user:

```
$ sudo chown -R postgres .
$ sudo su
# su postgres
$ pg_ctl stop -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data
waiting for server to shut down.... done
server stopped
```

Comment: Well, it is stated in the PostgreSQL docs that the DB is supposed to run as the `postgres` user.

Comment: On Windows 10, I must start pg_ctl command (in a bat file) as administrator.